# How we get the success messages

Tags: user-registration

How we can get the success messages like we can get the error messages by simple using the variable `$error` . So there is any other variable like `$success`. Currently i am using this code to register a new user. so after registeration i want to display success message.

```
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'adduser' ) {
    $user_pass = wp_generate_password();
    $userdata = array(
        'user_login' => esc_attr( $_POST['user_name'] ),
        'user_pass' => esc_attr( $_POST['pass1'] ),
        'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ),
        'user_url' => esc_attr( $_POST['website'] ),
        'description' => esc_attr( $_POST['description'] ),
        'role' => get_option( 'default_role' ),
    );

    if ( !$userdata['user_login'] )
        $error = __('A username is required for registration.', 'frontendprofile');
    elseif ( username_exists($userdata['user_login']) )
        $error = __('Sorry, that username already exists!', 'frontendprofile');

    elseif ( !is_email($userdata['user_email'], true) )
        $error = __('You must enter a valid email address.', 'frontendprofile');
    elseif ( email_exists($userdata['user_email']) )
        $error = __('Sorry, that email address is already used!', 'frontendprofile');
    else if ( $_POST['pass1'] !== $_POST['pass2'] ) {
        $error = __('Sorry, Passwords must match', 'frontendprofile');
    }
    else if ( strlen( $_POST['pass1'] ) < 6 ) {
        $error = __('Sorry, Passwords must be at least six characters long', 'frontendprofile');
    }
    else{
        $new_user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
        wp_new_user_notification($new_user, $user_pass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare $success variable and use it to display success message as following.

Declare $success variable and assign success message to it if user is registered successfully as following :

```
$success = '';
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'adduser' ) {
$user_pass = wp_generate_password();
$userdata = array(
    'user_login' => esc_attr( $_POST['user_name'] ),
    'user_pass' => esc_attr( $_POST['pass1'] ),
    'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ),
    'user_url' => esc_attr( $_POST['website'] ),
    'description' => esc_attr( $_POST['description'] ),
    'role' => get_option( 'default_role' ),
);

if ( !$userdata['user_login'] )
    $error = __('A username is required for registration.', 'frontendprofile');
elseif ( username_exists($userdata['user_login']) )
    $error = __('Sorry, that username already exists!', 'frontendprofile');

elseif ( !is_email($userdata['user_email'], true) )
    $error = __('You must enter a valid email address.', 'frontendprofile');
elseif ( email_exists($userdata['user_email']) )
    $error = __('Sorry, that email address is already used!', 'frontendprofile');
else if ( $_POST['pass1'] !== $_POST['pass2'] ) {
    $error = __('Sorry, Passwords must match', 'frontendprofile');
}
else if ( strlen( $_POST['pass1'] ) < 6 ) {
    $error = __('Sorry, Passwords must be at least six characters long', 'frontendprofile');
}
else{
    $new_user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
 if (!is_wp_error($return) ){
    $success = __($userdata['user_login'].' User registered $userdata['user_login'].', 'frontendprofile');
    wp_new_user_notification($new_user, $user_pass);
}
}
}
```

And you can use that $success variable to display message as following:

```
if($success)
     echo $success;
```